# Not able to set focus on a textbox

Tags: wpf, focus

My main window has a content control that I load a user control into.  I can't seen to set the focus to a text box in the user control.  I've tried several suggested methods like `textBox1.Focus()` and `Keyboard.Focus()` and `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement()` but they don't seem to work.

I'm not tied to this way of loading the user control if there is a better way.  It seems like I'm missing something pretty fundamental regarding either focus or the ContentControl so I thought I'd ask the experts instead of continuing to shot gun the problem.

Any ideas?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Name="NavFrame"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    this.NavFrame.Content = new UserControl1();
    base.OnInitialized(e);
}
```

UserControl1.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,79,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
</Grid>
```

UserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Focus();
    // FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, textBox1);
    // Keyboard.Focus(textBox1);
    base.OnInitialized(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the `textBox1.Focus()` into the loaded event for the user control rather than `OnInitialized` it seems to work correctly.

```
<UserControl ...
    Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="textBox1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

Something as simple as this works as well, if you want to give focus on times other than OnLoad...

UserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
public void FireTextBoxFocus()
{
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
UserControl1 ctrl = new UserControl1();
ContentControl1.Content = ctrl;
ctrl.FireTextBoxFocus();
```

Comment: @tzerb I edited my answer with another easy solution that I actually tested this time =).